# JavaScript Problema al crear cache

Tags: javascript, html, cache

**Buenas**

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y actualmente estoy tratando de almacenar mi Index.html y Codigo.js en el cache, actualmente estoy trabajando con un servidor local en mi pc con Xamp, hasta el momento no lo he logrado ya que mi función suelta un error que no logro solucionar, agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda que puedan darme.

**Codigo JavaScript:**

```
"use stric";

caches.open("archivos-estaticos").then(cache =>{

    cache.addAll(['index.html','codigo.js']);

});
```

Es lo que estoy ejecutando de momento y no logro que corra, estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

**Error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request scheme 'file' is unsupported
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Cambia `use stric` por `use strict`, y comprueba que estés cargando la página desde el servidor. El error dice `Request scheme 'file'` y eso me suena a que no se está usando el protocolo HTTP para pedir los archivos.

Comment: @MarcosRodríguez Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, precisamente en algún punto estuve haciendo algo mal con mi servidor, hoy comprobando la conexión funciono todo perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
"use strict";

caches.open("archivos-estaticos").then(cache => {
    cache.addAll(['index.html', 'codigo.js'])
        .then((a) => { console.log(a) })
        .catch((err) => { console.warn(err) })
});
```

Asegúrate de que la página está siendo cargada a través del servidor. Los archivos `index.html` y `codigo.js` tiene que proveerlos el mismo. Comprueba que existan los dos en la raiz o directorio desde donde se están solicitando.

Si el error que devuelve es el log amarillo y dice:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request scheme 'file' is unsupported
```

Significa que estás usando el protocolo file (`file:///.../index.html`) y no hay un servidor que te esté entregando dichos archivos.

Si dice:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'Cache' on 'addAll': Request failed
```

Significa que el servidor no ha encontrado el archivo, posiblemente `codigo.js`, si es así, comprueba que exista.

Casi se me olvida, si la consola muestra `undefined`, significa que no se ha producido ningún error en la promesa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y los tips, al parecer ayer estuve haciendo en todo momento algo mal con mi servidor, hoy comprobando al completo la conexión con el servidor funciono de maravillas.